# Is there a handy way to get the name of a Spring Bean/Service?

Tags: java, spring

I could do SomeSpringService.class.getSimpleName() and lowercase the first letter to get the default bean name, but I'm wondering if there is a simple Spring function that could find this for me? Simple meaning I'm not getting the application context, or building a factory, or such.

Thank you

Update: current hack

```
@Service
public class ServiceSelector
{
   @Autowired
   Map<String, IThing> implementations;

   public SomethingInterface getDecisionStrategy(AnEnum type)
   {
      SomethingInterface something;

      switch (type)
      {
        case ONE:
           implementation = findInstance(Impl1.class);
           break;
        case TWO:
           implementation = findInstance(Impl2.class);
           break;
         default:
            implementation = findInstance(Impl2.class);
      }
      return implementation;
   }

   private SomethingInterface findInstance(Class clazz)
   {
      String className = clazz.getSimpleName();
      String defaultBeanName = Character.toLowerCase(className.charAt(0)) + className.substring(1);
      return implementations.get(defaultBeanName);
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you need it for? You can implement `BeanNameAware` if you want a bean to be aware of it's name.

Comment: That's a good idea, and I'll upvote it if you add it as an answer - but it doesn't work for me as I'm not working from an instance.

Answer (score 7):

your bean can implement BeanNameAware, so you must add setBeanName(String beanName), in your class. Spring IoC will return your bean name.

For example:

```
public class Control implements BeanNameAware{
   private String beanName;
    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String s) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No; you're basically asking to invert a map. Beans can be registered with arbitrary and even multiple names, and the name can come from a variety of places at runtime--the class name, a component annotation, an `@Configuration` method, XML, and more. The only way to find the name(s) given a specific object would be to enumerate all the beans and find which entries match.

**Update:** Based on your code sample, it looks like you're trying to go a very long way around two simpler patterns. The more direct implementation of your current approach is to just use the class to ask for the bean directly:

```
@Autowired ApplicationContext ctx;
...
implementation = ctx.getBean(Impl2.class);
```

However, this seems like a case for Replace Conditional with Polymorphism: While you've phrased your question in general terms, it's *usually* the case that it's appropriate either for the enum to know the class (so the switch is replaced by `strategy.getImplementingClass()`) or for the services to know information directly (see, for example, how [`Converter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) instances identify the objects they can operate on to their users) and for you to get a `Set<IThing>` and iterate over them to query for a suitable match.

Comment: True - not thrilled, but I used my getSimpleName() solution, which is at least more flexible than hardcoding bean name.

Comment: @orbfish You never did explain what this is for. There's almost certainly a cleaner method to accomplish your actual task.

Comment: If you wire an interface as a map of <String, Interface> it will give you a map where the key is the bean name and the value is the instance. I'm trying to retrieve the instance based on knowing the class. As you say though, it's a runtime configuration, so class name is just an educated guess.

Comment: @orbfish Wait, so you're just trying to find beans by type?

Comment: Indeed - really, I'm trying to find the bean name of the single instance wired in by @Service.

Comment: @orbfish Why? What are you going to do with that name?

Comment: I just updated with my current working version. Before, the method call was just implementations.get("defaultBeanName")

Answer (score 3):

`org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory#getBeanNamesForType(java.lang.Class<?>)`

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils#beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory, java.lang.Class<?>)`

Comment: Code-only answers aren't too helpful, please consider adding if and why it works.